# This code is working in snippet but not in blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

This is my [blog](http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/)  i have added the code like below in my blog. The below code is working correctly in snippet like in the example below but it is not working correctly in my blog which i use it in blogger platform should i use any jquery library to make it work. See the snippet below it is working fine in the snippet. my aim is to hide one widget if another widget displays but 2 widget displayed same time in my blog. [example fiddle is working fine](https://jsfiddle.net/uunzq61e/2/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var control1VisibleCheck = function () {
  var now = new Date();
  //TODO: modify this logic to your needs: have a look on the Date() object's members and methods to implement what you need
  if (now.getSeconds() % 20 == 0)    //I'd like to show control1 on even minutes
    return true;
  return false;
}

if (control1VisibleCheck())
  document.getElementById('multi-search-groups').style.display = 'none';
else
  document.getElementById('multi-search').style.display = 'none';
</script>



<div id="multi-search">
  <select id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn">
    <option value="" />Columns
    <option value="apple+" />apple
    <option value="grapes+" />grapes
  </select>
  <select id="cmbSidebar" name="cmbSidebar">
    <option value="" />Sidebars
    <option value="mango+" />mango
    <option value="berry+" />berry

  </select>
</div>

<div id="multi-search-groups">
  <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br />
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value="" />
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option />Dallas Cowboys
      <option />New York Giants
      <option />Philadelphia Eagles
      <option />Washington Redskins
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>

<!--div id="control1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
</div>
<div id="control2" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: green;">
</div-->
```

The below code is working fine

```js
var control1VisibleCheck = function () {
  var now = new Date();
  //TODO: modify this logic to your needs: have a look on the Date() object's members and methods to implement what you need
  if (now.getSeconds() % 2 == 0)    //I'd like to show control1 on even minutes
    return true;
  return false;
}

if (control1VisibleCheck())
  document.getElementById('multi-search-groups').style.display = 'none';
else
  document.getElementById('multi-search').style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<div id="multi-search">
  <select id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn">
    <option value="" />Columns
    <option value="apple+" />apple
    <option value="grapes+" />grapes
  </select>
  <select id="cmbSidebar" name="cmbSidebar">
    <option value="" />Sidebars
    <option value="mango+" />mango
    <option value="berry+" />berry

  </select>
</div>
  
<div id="multi-search-groups">
  <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br>
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
      <option>New York Giants</option>
      <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
      <option>Washington Redskins</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>

<!--div id="control1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
</div>
<div id="control2" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: green;">
</div-->
```

Comment: @JaromandaX please look at this https://jsfiddle.net/uunzq61e/2/ it is working fine in fiddle without any external resources but i dont know why it is not working in blogger i have pasted the code above which iam using in my blog

Comment: @JaromandaX but how can i make same thing  to work should i add any jquery library....?

Comment: but i have also implemented in other blog also i mean just test blog but there also it won't work it is clean test blog

Comment: Which jquery code.....?

Comment: Another test blog http://newupdatesvijay.blogspot.in/ here also it wont worked

Comment: @JaromandaX Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null but not after adding the code before also i got this type of erros...

Comment: it shows error here document.getElementById('multi-search-groups').style.display = 'none';

Comment: @JaromandaX Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null in this document.getElementById('multi-search-groups').style.display = 'none';  at http://newupdatesvijay.blogspot.in/

Comment: @JaromandaX can u mention in answer or an example would help me

Comment: @JaromandaX worked http://newupdatesvijay.blogspot.in/ view now

Comment: @jaromandaX it worked http://newupdatesvijay.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your fiddle doesnt work correctly either, as suggested in the comments execute your JavaScript after the page (document) is ready:

### JavaScript document ready function

```
(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

### full JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    var control1VisibleCheck = function () {
      var now = new Date();
      //TODO: modify this logic to your needs: have a look on the Date() object's members and methods to implement what you need
      if (now.getMinutes() % 2 == 0)    //I'd like to show control1 on even minutes
        return true;
      return false;
    }

    if (control1VisibleCheck())
      document.getElementById('multi-search-groups').style.display = 'none';
    else
      document.getElementById('multi-search').style.display = 'none';
});
```

**[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uunzq61e/3/)**

Comment: i have put script after div it worked check http://newupdatesvijay.blogspot.in/  but let me check with your code also

Answer (score 0):

Solved! i added my `<script>` after `</div>`  tag it worked like below is my code which i have got in my [blog](http://easyuiimages.blogspot.in/) .

I got result what i want i mean if one widget is hided and another widget to be shown to show for this i used  `if (now.getSeconds() % 2 == 0)`  the below is my full code which i have added in my blog. I have just changed i mean i have added the `script` tag after `div` it worked.

```
<div id="multi-search">
  <select id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn">
    <option value="" />Columns
    <option value="apple+" />apple
    <option value="grapes+" />grapes
  </select>
  <select id="cmbSidebar" name="cmbSidebar">
    <option value="" />Sidebars
    <option value="mango+" />mango
    <option value="berry+" />berry

  </select>
</div>

<div id="multi-search-groups">
  <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br />
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value="" />
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option />Dallas Cowboys
      <option />New York Giants
      <option />Philadelphia Eagles
      <option />Washington Redskins
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var control1VisibleCheck = function () {
  var now = new Date();
  //TODO: modify this logic to your needs: have a look on the Date() object's members and methods to implement what you need
  if (now.getSeconds() % 2 == 0)    //I'd like to show control1 on even minutes
    return true;
  return false;
}

if (control1VisibleCheck())
  document.getElementById('multi-search-groups').style.display = 'none';
else
  document.getElementById('multi-search').style.display = 'none';
</script>
```